get the list of files from google shared drive folder
i write the code for get the list of files from google shared drive folder but the problem is it exclude the excel file.

FileList result = service.files().list()
        .setQ(query)
        .setDriveId(SHARED_DRIVE_ID) // Specify the shared drive ID
        .setSupportsAllDrives(true) // Supports shared drives
        .setIncludeItemsFromAllDrives(true) // Include items from all drives
        .setFields("files(id,name,mimeType,size)")
        .setQ("'" + folderId + "' in parents")
        .set("corpora", "drive") // Set
        .execute();



I want to get all the files present in particular folder including excel file.

Show us the complete code with input of query, SHARED_DRIVE_ID and folderId. Perhaps you filter something out in there.

I agree with @bobbel. It's likely that .setQ(query) is filtering out the Excel files you're looking for which is why it's not returning in the results. All the other parameters seem to be in order.
